# Design approach for multiple if else statement?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have  method which  returns sql query as string. This method  consider parameter  'level' , based on this
  parameter  there are multiple if else statement  like

```
   if(level.equals("A1")){
    // add some  field in query
   }
   else if (level.equals("A2"))
   {
    // add some  field  and logic in query
   }
   ..

   so on
```

In future number of levels are going to increase and  I don`t want to write pesky if else statements so  I am looking for cleaner and maintainable design approach for this scenario.
   I am thinking of strategy design pattern  but not sure whether it is best for this scenario.

Comment: `A1,A2,...` are not valid as `characters`.

Comment: https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. `if`/`else if` as you've indicated.
2. A [`switch` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).
3. A `Map` with the keys being the level string and the values being references of a functional interface type (`Runnable` or an appropriate interface from [`java.util.function`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html), or your own) you can initialize with [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), [lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), anonymous class instances, or even concrete class instances as required.

Here's an example of that last option, using the most basic functional interface, `Runnable`, with method references:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Example {
    private Map<String, Runnable> handlers;

    public Example() {
        this.handlers = new HashMap<String, Runnable>();
        this.handlers.put("A1", this::a1action);
        this.handlers.put("A2", this::a2action);
    }

    private void a1action() {
        System.out.println("Action A1");
    }

    private void a2action() {
        System.out.println("Action A2");
    }

    public void handleAction(String action) {
        Runnable handler = this.handlers.get(action);
        if (handler == null) {
            System.out.println("No handler for '" + action + "'");
        } else {
            handler.run();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Example ex = new Example();
        ex.handleAction("A1");
        ex.handleAction("A2");
        ex.handleAction("A3");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `enum` to list the operations and use `valueOf` to work out which to use.

```
enum Levels {
    A1 {
        @Override
        void doSomethingToTheQuery(Query q) {
            // add some  field in query
        }
    },
    A2{
        @Override
        void doSomethingToTheQuery(Query q) {
            // add some  field  and logic in query
        }
    };

    abstract void doSomethingToTheQuery(Query q);
}

public void test() {
    // Lookup the level and do hack the query.
    Levels.valueOf("A1").doSomethingToTheQuery(q);
}
```

You can then add new levels just by adding to the `enum`.